What's the "checking account" in XCM and what other accounts should a parachain migrate in the pallet-balance v0 to v1 migration
The term "checking account" pops up in one or two spots in the code, in this migration for instance: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12813.
But I can't find any docs on this. Seems to be related to teleports, but it's hard to figure out without even in-code docs. Does it even make sense for a parachain to have a checking account?
Also, what other accounts should be considered when applying this migration? It basically marks funds held by these accounts as "owned by the system", but this also seems like a slightly ambiguous concept to me.
